# Unable to boot from usb - Apple Mac Mini

Tags: system-installation, usb, bios

I have been running a old Mac mini 2010 with elementary os as a Htpc but have started having a few issues and was going to change to lubuntu 16.10. I created a usb stick in unetbootin and restarted the computer but couldnt see lubuntu as an option the bios boot menu. Since then I haven't been able get into elementary os or boot from the usb stick. Is there any workaround to either get into elementary os and start again or boot lubuntu from the usb drive?

Thanks in advance I'm new at the whole ubuntu/linux game

Comment: Did you configure your BIOS to first try to boot from USB device?

Comment: You should modify your title in adding apple MAC device

Comment: Title edited - dubis. Yaron - I'm not sure how I would do that?

Answer (score 0):

Some touch combination are available by holding down certain keys during startup on MAC device

After reading this page [Mac features touch combo](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) You should press `C`  immediately after you press the power button.

Let us know if is working on your MAC.

Comment: Whether I press the c key or not I end up in gnu grub version 2.02 beta2 screen that has two options elementary and advanced options for elementary. At that point I can press c for command line but not sure if there's anything I can input to boot from the usb.

Comment: There is a miss understanding is it a BIOS problem or a Grub problem. If you got your grub but you're not sure with which device you're working on, let the system start normally. You should see if you're running on your USB device or on your hard disk device